# Solution set of modulus inequations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$|2x+5|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$$

What will be the solution set?

My attempt:

1. For $x \in \left(-\infty,-\dfrac{5}{2}\right)$
   $x\geq -\dfrac{11}{4}$
2. For $x \in \left[-\dfrac{5}{2},\infty\right)$
   $x\leq -\dfrac{9}{4}$

Now do we have to take union or intersection? How do we find what to do? In this case we have to take intersection, but why?

[image]

Comment: Say we have $|u| \le \frac{1}{2}$ This means we want all numbers $u$ that gives us distance from 0 less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. That is $-\frac{1}{2} \le u \le \frac{1}{2}$ Now you can actually replace my $u$ with your $2x+5$ expression and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite you inequality as $$|x-(-5/2)| \le \frac 14.  \tag 1$$ and interpret the left hand side as the distance between the points $x$ and $-\frac12$ on the ncumber line. so what you are looking for is all points $x$ that is within a distance of $\frac 14$ from the points $-\frac 52.$  they are the points $x$ between $-\frac{11}4$ and $-\frac 94.$ that is $$-\frac{11}4 \le x \le -\frac 94. $$

Answer (score 2):

For real $x,$

$$|2x+5|\le\dfrac12\iff(2x+5)^2\le\left(\dfrac12\right)^2$$

$$\iff(4x+10)^2\le1\iff(4x+10-1)(4x+10+1)\le0$$

$$\iff\left[x-\left(-\dfrac94\right)\right]\cdot\left[x-\left(-\dfrac{11}4\right)\right]\le0$$

Now if $(x-a)(x-b)\le0$ where $a<b;$ we can prove $a\le x\le b$

Comment: Sir, from the answer at the last I read that we take union between the solution sets of two cases when the inequality sign is greater than and we take intersection when it is less than. Can you tell me if it's always true? If it is, why am I not able to solve this problem correctly with that method. $(( x^2-7|x|+10)/(x^2-6x+9))<0$

Comment: As $x^2-6x+9=(x-3)^2>0$ for $x\ne3$ so, we can safely focus on $$0>x^2-7|x|+10=(|x|-2)(|x|-5)$$  as for $x^2=|x|^2$ for real $x$

Comment: Sir would you please have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391121/438329.

Comment: @user38227, What is this?

Comment: The official question I have just asked few minutes ago, I have explained in detail what my doubts are and how do I go about and solve similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Because:

$$|2x+5|\leq\dfrac{1}{2} \iff -\dfrac{1}{2}\leq 2x+5\leq\dfrac{1}{2} \\
\iff -\dfrac{1}{2}-5\leq 2x\leq\dfrac{1}{2}-5 \iff \frac{-11}{14}\leq x\leq \frac{9}{4}$$

which means that $\frac{-11}{14}\leq x$ **and** $x\leq \frac{9}{4}$, so you have to take the intersection, because you have to satisfy both inequatilities simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if $$|x|>\dfrac{1}{2}$$ then $$+x>\dfrac{1}{2} \vee x<-\dfrac{1}{2}$$
Here is the trick, the $\vee$ reminds you to take the union. $\vee$ and $\cup$, $\wedge$ and $\cap$

Comment: I actually solved quite a lot of questions with this but does it always work? Because I'm not able to solve this correctly ($( x^2-7|x|+10)/(x^2-6x+9))<0$ I took intersection but the answer comes if I take union. Please explain.

Comment: When you have $a/b<0$ your answer comes when $a>0 \wedge b<0 $ and when $a>0 \wedge b>0$, so the right answer is union. I think this example will help you on the right method ;)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a and b? What are they? Can you solve my question or show any other similiar example to show what you mean? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, when $a/b$ is negative shouldn't both $a$and $b$ be of opposite signs?

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ should he opposite  signs. They both are mathematical expressions. If you have $\frac{a}{b}<0$ then multipl both for $b^2$ and then you have $a\cdot b<0$.