# Absolute Value Inequality Case Study

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Okay so I did a lot of research online and on stackexchange on solving absolute value inequalities.

*I read in an answer here that on having different set of values in different cases, we take **union** when the inequality is **greater than** and take **intersection** when the inequality is **less than**. This logic solved almost all of my problems correctly however, I came across a question which seems to be an exception to this rule*.

$\frac{( x^2-7|x|+10)}{(x^2-6x+9)}<0$

As we see, the denominator is necessarily always positive except for $x=3$, so it won't affect the inequality in general, on solving the two cases, one while opening the mod normally and the other while opening it up with a negative sign, I got two cases as follows.

$x\in (-2,-5)$ and $x\in (2,3) \cup (3,5)$

Now according to the **rule** the answer should be the intersection of the two cases since the inequality sign in the original problem is **less than**. However, the answer in my book arrives on taking the union.

*Someone just please let me know what is going wrong and if this rules won't work everytime, is there any solid and purely logical rule that I can use blindfoldy for every problem without having to consider checking the values to figure out whether to take union or intersection? Please help me guys, I'm literally going mad over it.*

At last, **Thanks a lot for showing patience and interest in this querry**, thanks for giving me your precious time.

Comment: I suppose you're looking at $-7|x|< -x^2-10$; this is not an "intersection" (because of the negative on the left). Put it in the form $7|x|> x^2+10$ to see a "union" should be used (specifically, $7x>x^2+10$ or $7x<-x^2-10$).

Comment: Yea I see it now, but the rule said observe the inequality signs in the original form of the problem.

Comment: @David Mitra so what you're actually saying is that to observe the inequality signs, I should always check and make sure that my modulus term has a positive sign? Is it so?

Comment: Yes; you want, e.g., either $|x|<\rm something$, or  $|x|>\rm something$, before writing the equivalent form.

Comment: Thanks David. One last querry to be resolved.

Comment: How do I go about and figure that out in this problem? $\frac{x^2-|x|-12}{x-3}>2x$. How do I take the $|x|$ term in consideration in this problem?

Comment: Is it safe to say that the rule that I previously described turns to complete opposite when the modulus term has a negative sign with it in the original problem?

Comment: Safe or not, I don't think it's a good idea to think of things that way. Just always try to  get the inequality in the *exact* form that the rule specifies. Your second problem is a bit more complicated, since the denominator can take both signs. First, break it into cases: the case when $x>3$ and the case when $x<3$. For the first case your answer will be "$x>3$ and $x$ in the solution set of $x^2-|x|-12> 2x(x-3)$".

Comment: David can you solve one question completely for me so that I have an idea of how things are really done? $\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2}>1$

Comment: Case 1: $x+2>0$. Then
$$
\eqalign{{|x+3| + x\over x+2}>1 &\iff |x+3| +x>x+2 \cr
&\iff |x+3| > 2\cr
&\iff x+3>2{\rm\ or\ } x+3<-2\cr
&\iff x>-1{\rm\ or\ }x<-5.}$$
So the solution set for case 1 is $x>-1$ (since in case 1, we have $x>-2$).

Now solve for the case when $x+2<0$... 

The final answer is the union of the solution sets for the two cases.

Comment: Can you write the final answer as well? Whatever you're getting? Cause my final answers not matching with that of the book. Also, could you correct your syntax? It's unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the intervals method.

We need to solve $$\frac{(|x|-5)(|x|-2)}{(x-3)^2}<0.$$
$(|x|-5)(|x|-2)=0$ for $x\in\{\pm5,\pm2\}$ and $(x-3)^2=0$ for $x=3$.

Now, you can make the following.

1. Draw the $x$-axes and put there the points: $-5$, $-2$, $2$, $3$ and $5$;
2. Take the right interval $(5,+\infty)$ and define the sign of our function on this interval.

Easy to see that the sign is $+$.

3. Now, if a degree of the point is odd then the sign is changed, while if the degree of the point is even then the sign is not changed.

Thus, we get the following signs: $$+,-,+,-,-,+,$$
which gives, the answer:
$$(-5,-2)\cup(2,3)\cup(3,5).$$

This method gives possibility to write the answer immediately  without distinction between cases.

Comment: How do you do it? Can I learn this technique from somewhere? Please let me know.

Comment: Also, I've edited that previous question of mine. I've put up an image showing my effort. Would you please let me know what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll try to explain. It's very useful and easy method, but hard enough to explain this in the net.