# Help solve the function $\frac{3x^2 + x}{2x - x^2}$

Tags: functions

I have an equation

$D(x): \frac{3x^2 + x}{2x-x^2} \leq 0$

I calculated the domain as:

$D = \mathbb{R} - \{0;2\}$

The result of the equation should be:

$P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}; x \in (-\infty; -\frac{1}{3} \rangle
 \cup(2; \infty) \}$

I am unable to calculate this equation correctly because of the power. Could you please push me in calculating this equation?

Comment: What does the semicolon mean? I take it to mean, say $\{0; n\} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots , n\}$ but I'd like to clarify if that's ok.

Comment: @MrPie You're right, semicolons shouldn't be there ... I should use a comma as a separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In those case we need study separately the sign for numerator and denominator, that is

- $3x^2 + x=x(3x+1)\implies$ positive in $(-1/3,0)$ and negative in $(-\inf,-1/3)\cup(0,\inf)$
- $2x-x^2=x(2-x) \implies \cdots$

Finally we can determine the sign for the overall expression.

Comment: So if you understand it correctly, you can be an inequality where the numerator and denominator are dealt with separately?

Comment: @FilipSedivy The key point is that once you know the sign of numerator N and denominator D you can find th overall sign by the ratio N/D. A graph is useful to solve easily. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @FilipSedivy Refer to the following [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1263975/505767).

Comment: I can deduce the graph from it, and it is more clear to me now. I just needed to orientate more in the equation and take the first step. Thanks you for your help! +1

Comment: @FilipSedivy You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Begin by observing that

if $b\ne 0$ then

$\frac ab$ has exactly the same sign than the product $ ab$.

thus, your inequation, is equivalent to

$$(3x^2+x)(2x-x^2)\le 0$$
for $$x\in \Bbb R \backslash \{0,2\}$$

this inequation can be written as

$$x^2(3x+1)(2-x)\le 0$$

or
$$(3x+1)(2-x)\le 0$$

whose final solution is 
$$x\in (-\infty,\frac{-1}{3}] \cup (2,+\infty)$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! +1

Comment: @FilipSedivy I am your brother.